# MongoEngine Aggregation - pivot array to object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I am working on following MongoEngine classes

```
class User(Document):
    username = EmailField(primary_key=True)
    name = StringField()

class Asset(Document):
    users = ListField( ReferenceField("User") )
    remote = MapField( DynamicField() )
```

Sample documents of the above classes are

User:

```
{
    "_id" : "xyz@xyz.com",
    "name" : "xyz"
}
```

Asset:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5485asasansja"),
    "users" : ["xyz@xyz.com", "abc@abc.com"],
    "remote" : { "bytes" : 123,
                  "source" : "some source"
               }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5885asaskaia"),
    "users" : ["pqr@xyz.com", "abc@abc.com"],
    "remote" : { "bytes" : 345,
                  "source" : "another source"
               }
}
```

I want to get results using pipeline like

```
{
    "xyz@xyz.com" : {"some source": 45845, "another source": 5845},
    "abc@abc.com" : {"some source": 584, "another source": 986}
}
```

bottom line, want to get the sum of bytes according to its source for each user.

I tried with

```
pipeline = [

        {'$project':
             {'remote.source': 1, 'remote.bytes': 1 }},

        {'$unwind': '$users'},

        {'$lookup': {
            'from': 'user', 'localField': 'users', 'foreignField' : '_id', 'as':'user'
        }},

        {'$match': {'remote.source': {'$exists': True, '$ne': None}}},
        {'$project': {'username': '$user.username'}},

        {'$group':
             {'username':'$username','source': '$remote.source', 'count': {'$sum': 1}, 'size': {'$sum': '$remote.bytes'}}}
    ]

for each in Asset.objects().aggregate(*pipeline):
    print(each)
```

It does not return any result. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

See if this would do it for you:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$users" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          "k": "$users",
          "v": "$remote"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The idea is to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) the `users` then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) them via `data` which is a `key/value` array in order to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to form the final output **object** you are after.

You can see it [here working](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zLeta_EP-hU)